# Convert in stored procedure ms sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have stored procedure where select and filtering data. For example :

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar,[Date],120) , [FirstName] , [LastName]
FROM myDB
WHERE  (@Date IS NULL OR @Date = '' OR [Date] = @Date)
       (@FirstName IS NULL OR @FirstName  = '' OR [FirstName] = @FirstName)
       (@LastName IS NULL OR @LastName  = '' OR [LastName] = @LastName)
```

When i filtering by FirstName  or/and LastName it works , but when I want filter by Data it dont work , I think there is convert problem maybe ? I exec like :

```
exec myProc '2013-02-03','',''
```

Comment: "it dont work" - not very descriptive. also, that snippet won't compile...

Comment: What is the header of the procedure? So we can see parameter datatypes and order.

Comment: try using date conversion method in where condition also.. It may work

Comment: thank you guys for answering , when I write date and then execute it doesnt take any parametrs from table

Comment: Is the `Date` column a `DateTime` data type? A common problem is that a date, e.g. `2013-02-03`, often doesn't match a date/time, e.g. `2013-02-03 12:15:06.000`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible this be helpful for you -

```
SELECT 
      CONVERT(NVARCHAR,[Date],120) 
    , [FirstName] 
    , [LastName]
FROM myDB
WHERE ISNULL(@Date, [Date]) = [Date] --<--
    AND (ISNULL(@FirstName, '') = '' OR [FirstName] = @FirstName) 
    AND (ISNULL(@LastName, '') = '' OR [LastName] = @LastName)
```

Comment: thank you for answering but with this code is same result. When write date and then execute it doesnt take any parametrs from table

Comment: thank you for answering I am begginer in sql server how do it ?

Comment: A small breadcrumb - `Object Explorer` -> `<your db>` -> `Programmability` -> `Stored Procedures` -> `<your stored procedure (sp)>` -> `popup menu` -> `Script Stored Procedure AS` -> `CREATE`